# How is my React app able to use my Node REST API when its not accessible from the outside?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, api, web-applications

I have a React App running on port 3000, and a Node server exposing a REST API on port 3001. Ive set the firewall to only allow traffic through 3000, and indeed, when manually trying to access the api through a browser, the connection gets refused.

My React App however works as it should and is able to use the API. How is it doing this? Also, does this mean that my API is secure and it cant be accessed directly by malicious actors?

Comment: If you set your server to listen to port 3000 only, expected behavior is the server will block traffic from anywhere else but port 3000. I don't really know if that means you are COMPLETELY secure though.

Comment: Is your REST API using GET requests on 3001?

Answer (score 0):

In react `package.json` add proxy

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```